# Reporting Map Errors and timely Updates via the Android Maps2 API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Simply stated, we have a considerable number of users who noticed that "reported map problems" do not update on the Android Maps API in a timely fashion.

For example, when a missing address, new road, or any other issue is submitted via the "Report a Problem" interface on the Desktop Google Maps, is seems to update on the desktop versions and the main Google Maps application for Android quickly. However, the map database used for the 2.0 API do not seem to receive these updates for a much longer period; updates can take many days or even weeks.

Our Android application is used by Emergency first-responders who spend a great deal of time driving to locations. Due to this, they routinely find incorrect information or new road development that they would like to submit and see reflected on our application, but historically, their updates only appear on the Maps App and the Desktop Maps.

I recognize that any user submitted errors must be validated by the Google team, but it appears that the Android API maps exhibit a substantially longer lag between updates than any of the other products. We are frequently asked by our clients why this is the case, and I don't have any answer.

Is there any API hook to allow API users to report errors to maps, or is there some other protocol that would be more effective here? These users are a great resource for map updates, and it seems odd that this ability is apparently missing from the API, unless it was omitted intentionally to prevent some sort of abuse?

Also, are there any general guidelines for the update process for map data on the Android API relative to the other products? Specifically, is there a time frame that users should expect to see their updates shown on the API maps, when errors are submitted via the Desktop maps?

We've been mitigating this by allowing users to overlay their own markers for updated roads, but obviously an updated map is the preferred solution.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would think this would be a better question for Google itself instead of asking us. There is no written documentation that gives any information about the update process for a map tile

Comment: Agreed, which is why I was posting it here. Google specifically recommends Stack Overflow as one of their internal, developer monitored resources:[Google Support](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/)